# Adding tooltip not displaying the div in css

Tags: html, css

I have added a tooltip for a div but it is not displaying that div in front end.Here is the code which i have added.

HTML:

```
<a href="/admin/patients">
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <span class="tooltiptext">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 userslist">
                            <div class="user">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="userlist">
                                <ul class="lists">
                                    <div class="headertext">
                                        <li class="list1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Users: <?php echo $count_new_users; ?></li>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="left">
                                    <li class="list4">Doctors :<?php echo $count_all_doctors; ?></li>
                                    <li class="list4">Clinics : - <?php echo $count_all_clinics; ?></li>
                                    <li class="list4">Hospitals - <?php echo $count_all_hospitals; ?></li>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="right">
                                    <li class="list4">Pharmacies - <?php echo $count_all_pharmacy; ?></li>
                                    <li class="list4">Labs - <?php echo $count_all_labs; ?></li>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
 }
 .tooltip .tooltiptext {
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 120px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 5px 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 125%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -60px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
 }

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 }
```

If i hover on this div i need to display that data like doctors,clinics,hospitals etcc..but when i added tooltip it is not displaying that div itself.Here is the fiddle link how the div displays in front end.

https://jsfiddle.net/eocw8vaj/1/

Comment: You can add a tooltip to any element with the `title` attribute ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the code like this

```
                    <div class="userlist">
                    <ul class="lists">
                    <span data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" id="pendingApprovalCnt" title="Providers :<?php echo $count_all_providerss; ?><br/>
                    Doctors :<?php echo $count_all_doctors; ?><br/>
                    Clinics : - <?php echo $count_all_clinics; ?><br/>
                    Clinics : - <?php echo $count_all_clinics; ?><br/> 
                    Pharmacies - <?php echo $count_all_pharmacy; ?><br/>
                    Labs - <?php echo $count_all_labs; ?>">
                        <div class="headertext">
                            <li class="list1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Providers :<?php echo $count_all_providerss; ?></li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <li class="list4">Doctors :<?php echo $count_all_doctors; ?></li>
                            <li class="list4">Clinics : - <?php echo $count_all_clinics; ?></li>
                            <li class="list4">Clinics : - <?php echo $count_all_clinics; ?></li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <li class="list4">Pharmacies - <?php echo $count_all_pharmacy; ?></li>
                            <li class="list4">Labs - <?php echo $count_all_labs; ?></li>
                        </div>                              
                    </ul>
                    </span>
                </div>
```